# image upload error in php codeigniter [The upload path does not appear to be valid.]

Tags: php, file-upload, multipartform-data, codeigniter-3, image-upload

I was using php codeigniter 2.x now i updated it to 3.x, after that my upload code is not working.
this is my code. please go though it. 
when this code is working always getting the error

> The upload path does not appear to be valid.

```
$this->load->library('upload');
    $session = $this->ifisSession();
    $uploadfolder = 'profileImgs';

    $fullPath = 'abc';
    $imageconfig['upload_path'] = $fullPath;
    $imageconfig['max_size'] = (1024); // 1mb file size
    $imageconfig['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $imageconfig['max_width'] = (1024 );
    $imageconfig['max_height'] = (1024);
    $fieldName = 'profileimage';
    //$uploadfilename = $_FILES[$fieldName];
    $uploadfilename = $_FILES[$fieldName]['name'];
   // printv($uploadfilename, 'this ihere');

    $fileinfo = pathinfo($uploadfilename);

    if (isset($fileinfo['extension'])) {

        $ext = $fileinfo['extension'];
        $imageconfig['file_name'] = $session['firstname'] . '_' . $session['user_id_pk'] . '_' . uniqid() . '.' . $ext;
    }


    $this->load->library('upload', $imageconfig);

    if (!$this->upload->do_upload('profileimage')) {

        $error = $this->upload->display_errors();
        $data['data']['profileUpdate_error'] = $error;
        // move to profile page with erro message
    } else {

        $profileUploadinfo = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        $profileimgurl = '';
        $res = $this->Model_userinfo->updateProfileImg($session['user_id_pk'], $profileimgurl);
        if($res > 0){
            $data['data']['profileUpdate_success'] = 'Profile Updated';
        }else{
            $data['data']['profileUpdate_error'] = 'Profile Not updated';
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is `$fullPath` value?

Comment: $config['upload_path']   = './uploads/';   i got some example like this, this one also not working.  can you advice what is exactly here.